# string choice condition is met, class is not called

Tags: java, eclipse, class

EDIT again:

each time I run this and input the "String a", all methods get called and I don't know why.

I know its all newbie stuff but counter intuitively, there are too many tutorials and threads on java to properly troubleshoot basic issues like this.

import java.util.*;
   public class ShopTest {

```
public static Scanner navigate = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Scanner playerStats = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Scanner shop = new Scanner(System.in);

static int playerGold = 0;
static String items;
static int ironSword = 200;
static int rustySword = 75;
static int lightLeatherArmor = 50;
static int minorHealthpotion = 25;
static String bought = "item added to inventory";
static String notBought = "Sorry, you don't have enough for that!";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome player.\nWhat is your name?");
    String playerName = playerStats.next();
    System.out.println("\nAh!" + playerName + "\n\nWe've been expecting you.\nAs we agreed, you get half the gold now and half after you kill that goblin!\nYou recieved 150 gold.");
    playerGold = playerGold +150;
    Navigate();
    }

public static void Shop() {
    System.out.println("\nWelcome to my shop\nWould you like to see my wares?");
    String shopChoice1 = shop.next();

    if (shopChoice1.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("\nSee anything you need?\nIron sword: " + ironSword + "\nRusty sword: " + rustySword + "\nLight leather armor: " + lightLeatherArmor + "\nMinor health potion: " + minorHealthpotion);
        }
    String shopChoice2 = shop.next();{
        System.out.println("ok");
    if (shopChoice2.equals("iron sword")) {
        IronSword();}
    else if (shopChoice2.equals("rusty sword")) {
        RustySword();}
    else if (shopChoice2.equals("light leather armor")) {
        LightleatherArmor();}
    else if (shopChoice2.equals("minor health potion")) {
        MinorhealthPotion();}
    else if (shopChoice2.isEmpty()) {
        Shop();}
    }
}

public static void IronSword() {
    if (playerGold >= ironSword) 
        System.out.println(bought);
        items = items + "Iron sword,\n";
    if (playerGold < ironSword) 
        System.out.println(notBought);
        Shop();
}

public static void LightleatherArmor() {

    }

public static void RustySword() {
    if (playerGold >= rustySword)
        System.out.println(bought);
        items = items + "Rusty Sword,\n";
    if (playerGold < rustySword) 
        System.out.println(notBought);
        Shop();
    }

public static void MinorhealthPotion() {

    }

public static void Inn() {
    System.out.println("**You enter the inn and approach the barkeep**\nHow can I help you?");

}
public static void Inventory() {
    System.out.println("Gold: " + playerGold + "\nItems: \n" + items + "\n\n");
    Navigate();

}

public static void Navigate() {
    System.out.println("\nWhat next?\n  Shop\n  Inn\n   Inv");
    String a = navigate.nextLine();

        if (a.equals("shop")) 
            Shop();
        else if (a.equals("inn")) 
            Inn();
        else if (a.equals("inv")) 
            Inventory();
}
```

}

*need add more text for some reason!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*need add more text for some reason!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*need add more text for some

Comment: Since you don't show us what shop.next() does, we can't know what happens. Do a debug output or set a breakpoint after shopChoice2 = shop.next() to see what it contains. Also you should at least mention what language you are using (looks like java).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I do appreciate the time. I'm very new to this (obviously).
I tried to put in as little code as possible before so there was less for people to have to ready. I edited more back in, but I am only allowed to put in so much code without more text.

Comment: That's ok. Now we can see the class of the variable shop. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default delimiter for the Scanner is whitespace. Which means it will break up the string on every whitespace (space, tabs, newlines). So if you enter "iron sword" you will only get "iron" on shop.next() and "sword" on the call after.

Since you want to read in whole lines, you can set the Delimiter to a newline. Like this:

```
public static Scanner shop = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
```

The Javadoc for the Scanner class mentions this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

BTW: Which IDE do you use? If you are new to programming make yourself familiar with it's debugging features. You can set a breakpoint right after the shop.next() call and then inspect the content of shopChoice2. This would have shown you that shop.next() does not do what you expect it to do.

**EDIT:**

There is a mistake after you edited your code:

```
if (shopChoice2.equals("iron sword"))
    System.out.println("ok");
    IronSword();}
if (shopChoice2.equals("rusty sword"))
```

This should be:

```
if (shopChoice2.equals("iron sword")) {
    System.out.println("ok");
    IronSword();}
} else if (shopChoice2.equals("rusty sword"))
```

Only "System.out.println("ok");" is being called if the if statement is true. Note that only the next statement is called if an "if" statement is true. If you need more that one statement to be executed you need to enclose those in curly brackets. As a general rule one should **ALWAYS** use curly brackets with if statements. Even if there is only one statement. This helps avoiding making mistakes like that.

**EDIT 2:**

This should work. Find the differences to your code:

```
String shopChoice2 = shop.next();
System.out.println(shopChoice2);
if (shopChoice2.equals("iron sword")) {
    IronSword();"
} else if (shopChoice2.equals("rusty sword")) {
    RustySword();
} else if (shopChoice2.equals("light leather armor")) {
    LightleatherArmor();
} else if (shopChoice2.equals("minor health potion")) {
    MinorhealthPotion();
} else if (shopChoice2.isEmpty()) {
    Shop();
}
```

Comment: I added ".useDelimiter("\\n")"
Unfortunately it just caused "shopChoice1" to be ignored.

I'm gonna post a new question with a much less complicated format to look at.

Comment: Right, so. -_- 
Didn't realise I could only ask 1 question every 90min. Gonna edit one last time a with a simpler version of the same issue.

Comment: No need. just saw that you introduced a second mistake after you edited your code. I added it to my answer.

Comment: I changed what you said but still nothing. not even the "System.out.printLn("ok")" is not being called

Comment: Remove the Semicolon after the if: if (a.equals("num 1"))
        NumOne();
And use curly brackets (not necessary here, but good practice)

Comment: Didn't work. 
shopChoice2 if equal to "iron sword" should take you to IronSword():
shopChoice2 if equal to "rustysword" should take you to RustySword (): etc.
But none of the methods are being called.

In the simpler version above, all methods are being called instead of one

Comment: Made some corrections. Don't forget to add .useDelimiter("\\n"); to your shop scanner.

Comment: ok great, the fix for the simpler code worked. I'll compare the rest now.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Cleaned up a couple of things but it's still not calling the methods.
The string a is being recognized as "iron sword" instead of "iron" though.

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with  leaving the main method.

When i try call a class from the main method, there is no issue. But when I call the class from a "public static void Shop" to  "public static void RustySword" nothing happens.

I tested this on the simpler but fixed code. Using my main as the shop, I can call the methods outside of main. But once I gave the shop it's own method and got to the shop from my main, it all stopped working.

Comment: maybe not, damn this is hard -_-

Comment: Ok, I lost track of what you did and which part isn't working now. I think this is not the right place to fix more problems since it's not a discussion forum. Sorry. And yes it's hard. But only at first. Don't give up.

Comment: I completely agree, thanks for all the help, I'll figure it out